# Choosing the right sorted collection

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I am a bit in doubt on which collection to use for our data.

The domain is this (example):

For each supermarket we add a new item to a collection with a timestamp and total amount each time any customer pays at the register.

We currently do this:

We have a Dictionary collection with key = UniqueSupermarketID and value is a List<{timestamp, amount}>

Each time a customer pays we simply add a new item to the collection for the specific supermarket.

We need to extract data from this dictionary in a way that:

For a specified supermarket, get the newest cash register object with timestamp equaling "some timestamp"

We currently do this as:

```
supermarketDictionary["supermarket_01"]
    .OrderByDescending(i => t.TimeStamp)
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.TimeStamp == 'some timestamp')
```

This obviously quickly starts performing like crap - so I am trying to figure out which collection to store data in instead.

I am considering using a normal dictionary to hold the "supermarket id <-> cash register list" relation and using a SortedDictionary for the timestamp/amounts used as *keys*.

Is this the correct approach? I would of course need to implement IComparable correctly on the timestamp to get it to work right.

**Update 2014-01-03:**

There are currently about 7 million rows in the list in question. The usages of the lists in our system have been identified as these:

```
_states
    .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.WtgId == wtgId && x.IsAvailable && x.TimeStamp >= timeStamp);

_states
    .Where(x => x.WtgId == wtgId && x.IsAvailable && x.TimeStamp >= timeStamp && x.TimeStamp <= endDateTime)
    .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();

_states.Remove(state);

if (!_states.Contains(message))
    _states.Add(message);
```

Thanks,

/Jesper
Copenhagen, Denmark

Comment: If you are using a huge amount of data use a database. That is the only scaleable and rational way and then only load the data you need.

Comment: Where is your data actually stored?  In a database?  If so, what kind?

Comment: I assume you have a db behind it. So just let the db do the job for you.

Comment: @dev hedgehog: I doubt that they have a database behind. Otherwise they would not use a dictionary to save the customer payments but add it directly to the database. Either no database or bad design ;)

Comment: Also, why order and then iterate through the collection looking for a specific timestamp? Why not just look for the timestamp without ordering?

Comment: all: we do not have (for various reasons) a database at the point where the code is executed - hence our need to hold these collections in memory

Comment: @dcastro, that is actually a very good point - I hadn't thought about that. But it would still be a good idea to switch collection type, right? To SortedDictionary<,> due to the binary tree under the hood?

Comment: Doesn't have to be `SortedDictionary<TimeStamp,Decimal>`. Assuming that later additions have greater timestamps a `SortedList<TimeStamp,Decimal>` might be a better choice.

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm Did you read my answer, Jesper?

Comment: Why are you ignoring my answer?

Comment: Hi ondrej,

My appologies - but I have been otherwise occupied and have not been able to look into our performance issue for a couple of weeks. We are doing more or less equal numbers of lookups and inserts - and the collections get quite huge - +1 million rows in some cases. The trick is that we query the lists on 4-7 different properties depending on scenario with both "equal"-operations and "gte/lt"-operations. It would be a no-brainer to implement indexes for this in SQL Server, but I don't see how we could do these complex indexes in pure .Net.

Comment: Well, it is not that hard. If you wait for a week or so, I shall provide a solution along with some tests. It's enough interesting problem for me that I can devote a few hours to it once I have some.

Comment: Jesper, could you please give, for instance, the most hardcore case? The one you have provided is rather easy one if you keep your collection sorted. BinarySearch on a sorted list can find a matching value pretty quickly.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I'll add the info to the question tonight :)

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Hi, I have updated the original post with more details - I apologize for the delay :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** based on the update

All right, seeing what you really need sure helps to make a right decision. If your data comes already in order there is no need for a sorted collection and your four usages can be reduced to one ->

Searching for one item that matches some criteria

- adding with an existence check - adding is a cheap operation in non-sorted collections and existence check is just a searching for one item
- removing by item is also at the most one passing through a collection plus the remove operation itself which is also quite cheap (not in an array if done many times, though)

Try using PLINQ and carefully measure how it performs against LINQ. With so many entries, the difference should be nice.

```
_states.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault(...);
```

It will just create a few threads on the background and each of them will search some part of the collection and at the end results are merged. The .NET framework should choose the best number of threads for you, but if you feel like trying, apped `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(x)` where `x` is a number of threads it will use.